# Dumping stored procedure result to a text file programmatically

Tags: sql-server, export

How can I save stored procedure execution result to a text file? I need to do this from SQL script (not Management Studio nor external utility) and I need to preserve correct characters encoding (Unicode in this case).

Comment: SQLCLR is probably the way to go if it has to be done within T-SQL, though why does it have to be done within T-SQL? Why not use BCP or SSIS or SQLCMD? I have created a SQLCLR stored procedure that exports the results of a query to a text file. It it called **DB_BulkExport** and is part of the [SQL#](http://SQLsharp.com) library. However, this stored proc is only available in the Full version, not in the Free version. Also, how did you get UTF-8 data into SQL Server when it only stores strings as UTF-16 (outside of keeping it stored as VARBINARY or encoded in some other fashion)?

Comment: I should write Unicode instead of UTF-8…

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simplest method would be a 2 step approach :

1. Log the output of stored procedure to a physical table in the sql server database. e.g. `insert into dbo.X_sp_name_out exec dbo.sp_name`
2. Use `BCP OUT` or `SQLCMD` to export data to text file.
3. (**Optional.. but important** to manage table growth) Have a purging process to purge out the old records or before next execution of the SP, truncate the table.

Make sure you use <kbd>[**`N'your unicode data'`**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/mssqlisv/sql-server-2005-unicode-considerations)</kbd> when storing data.

You can think of using SSIS to do the same and schedule the package using SQL Agent job.

Comment: This is kind of what I ended with. I used `bcp` and run it with `xp_CmdShell`.
Btw, the comment about prefixing strings with `N` was also helpful, thanks!